# Несовместимые типы операндов

Tags: c++, условия, тернарный-оператор

```
char buf[6000];    
bool bturn;
char *cturn;    
strstr(buf, "HEXTURN") == NULL ? bturn = NULL : cturn = strstr(buf, "HEXTURN") + 7;
```

Мне надо проверить,есть ли подстрока "HEXTURN" в буфере buf(char buf[6000]),и если есть, то присвоить cturn первый символ после подстроки "HEXTURN",а если подстроки нет,то bturn = NULL,но у меня подчеркивает двоеточие и пишет что несовместимые типы операндов bool и char.Как такое может быть ,когда у меня bturn и cturn в отдельных блоках условия?

Comment: Формально можно привести к нужному типу `... ? (char *)(bturn = NULL) : ... `. Однако, 2 раза вызывать `strstr()` не слишком разумно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bturn = NULL
```

это выражение имеет тип `bool` - вы сами написали

```
bturn = NULL
```

А

```
cturn = strstr(buf, "HEXTURN") + 7;
```

имеет тип `char *` -

```
char *cturn;
```

А в тернарном операторе `a ? b : c` и `b`, и `c` должны быть одного типа... Это же - **одно выражение**. А как одно выражение может быть одновременно разных типов?

Так что используйте `if-else`.

Comment: Спасибо,понял,не знал.Я думал там могут быть любые выражения как в обычном if-else

Answer (score 2):

Условия замедляют программу, и лучше программу избавить от излишных условий. В данном случаи это делать легко _ не нужны никакие условия:

```
char* cturn;
bool bturn = cturn = strstr(buf, "HEXTURN");
cturn += 7*(size_t)bturn;
```

Comment: если строка будет не найдена,то strstr вернет NULL,после чего мы к NULL добавим 7,что является ошибкой.По этому нужно условие

Comment: верно, спасибо, я забыл умножить